# post data by ajax jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i want to save data in database by a button click.here is my code,in Firefox it do not work it show empty alert and data do not saved in table.

```
    $("#Save").click(function () {  
       var price = $("#price").val(); 
       var agent_1_id= $("#agent_1_id").val();
       var type = $("#type").val();
    $.post("ajax_files/myDeals.php",
             { 
              price: price,
              agent_1_id: agent_1_id,type:type
              },
            function(data) {
                alert(data);
      });           
});
```

click event fires and this function calls. Here is code on myDeals.php to save in table..

```
$price = $_REQUEST['price']; 
$agent_1_id = $_REQUEST['agent_1_id'];
$type = $_REQUEST['type'];
mysql_query('insert query here');

echo "Saved Successfully ";//this is not alerted?
```

Comment: were you able to verify if price, agent_1_id, and type have values? (ie with firebug, alertbox, etc...)

Comment: why not just remove the mysql_query(..), and test it again?

Comment: yes all these have values....i checked by alert

Comment: Have you tried checking if your mysql query is valid? Or at least, instead of running a query, simply echo out all the `$_REQUEST` variables and see what is passed to the `data` object in your AJAX call.

Comment: i run php file directly by url,it works fine

Comment: i just echo "Sucess"; and alert is still empty...

Answer (score 0):

Try the sample  sending the data as an object:

```
function end_incident() {
    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "http://www.example.co.uk/erc/end_incident.php",
       data: { name: "Daniel", phone: "01234123456" },
       success: function(msg){ 
            alert('Success!');
       }
    });
};
```

Comment: i removed all code from php code and just echo "Success" which is also not working